# How to remove the caching of JavaRDD caused by shuffle in Spark in streaming

Tags: apache-spark

Shuffle function results in caching of JavaRDD. How to remove the caching in Spark Streaming

Comment: Spark doesn't cache RDD unless you instruct it to. What do you mean when you said caching of JavaRDD caused by shuffle ? Can you give some code example ?

Comment: @Dikei Actually if you something more than basic APIs it can but I think OP is specifically thinking about shuffle files.

Comment: Thanks for your support i mean if i call JavaRDD MyRDD2= MyRDD.coalesce(8, true) setting boolean shuffle to true causes caching of JavaRDD in streaming. I want to remove cache after one streaming is over and other streaming start